# What happens when you take a cutting from a mature determinate tomato plant?

Tags: tomatoes, cuttings

If I take a cutting from a determinate tomato plant that has already produced fruit, will the cutting grow and produce, or will it just die, eventually? I know mature indeterminate tomato cuttings will grow and produce fruit, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will grow fine. I ran some tests (slightly less scientifically than I could have, but got results) on grafting/propagation via cuttings using scions/cuttings from vigorous seedlings, older determinate, and older indeterminate tomato plants.

Surprisingly, the differences were small/unnoticeable. The cuttings and grafts from the old determinate plants became rejuvenated, and took off growing like any young tomato plant.

This test was also used in the answering of this question:

- [Biological age of grafted plants](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23638/biological-age-of-grafted-plants)

Comment: Awesome. Did the cuttings grow fruit?

Comment: @Shule yeah, they grew like normal plants.